# Manipulate values based on advanced criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like so:

```
ID   Time   Index
1    TS     NDVI
2    TS     NDVI
1    ES     NDVI
1    LS     NDII
2    TS     NDII
2    ES     NDII
```

I also have a dictionary like so:

`replacement_map = {1 : 4, 2 : 5}`

and I want to replace `ID` in my df using the replacement map only when `Time == TS` and `Index == NDVI`

I am trying this code:

```
df = df.ix[df['Index'] == 'NDVI' & df['Time'] == 'TS', 'ID'].map(replacement_map)
```

but this returns:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

My desired output is:

```
   ID   Time   Index
    4    TS     NDVI
    5    TS     NDVI
    1    ES     NDVI
    1    LS     NDII
    2    TS     NDII
    2    ES     NDII
```

Comment: Brackets - `df.ix[(df['Index'] == 'NDVI') & (df['Time'] == 'TS'), 'ID'].map(replacement_map)`?

Comment: Yes that did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like one of operator precedence.  The `&` is taking higher precedence than the `==`, so that you are effectively comparing `'NDVI' & df['Time']`, which leads to the given error.

Use `()` around your boolean comparisons to change the order of operations and get your desired result.

You'll also need to preserve the existing values, since in the way you wrote it the entire DataFrame will be overwritten.  Try creating a reusable mask in an intermediate step:

```
mask = (df['Index'] == 'NDVI') & (df['Time'] == 'TS')
df.ix[mask, 'ID'] = df.ix[mask, 'ID'].map(replacement_map)
```

For me that yields the desired result:

```
   ID Time Index
0   4   TS  NDVI
1   5   TS  NDVI
2   1   ES  NDVI
3   1   LS  NDII
4   2   TS  NDII
5   2   ES  NDII
```